# Angular2: Can't test component with templateUrl using TestBed.compileComponent()

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to get the basics of Angular2 test API and TestBed.compileComponents() is driving me nuts. Either I call it like this:

```
beforeEach( done => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent]
  })
  .compileComponents().then( () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance();
  });
  done();
});
```

And then my component is undefined in my test (I believe since compileComponent is async, test is run before my var component gets a value)

Either like that (as describe in [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-external-template)):

```
beforeEach( async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent]
  }))
  .compileComponents();

beforeEach( () => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance();
});
```

But then I get the error: `This test module uses the component HomeComponent which is using a "templateUrl", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.`

Can anybody help on this ?

Forget to say I use webpack and RC6

Comment: What happens if you call done() when the compileComponents has compiled the components, i.e. inside the function passed to then()?

Comment: @JBNizet same thing, I get an undefined component. Great angular2 book btw

Comment: can you show a code and template of your component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
describe('FooComponent', function () {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [FooComponent]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
```

You don't need asynchronicity here.

Comment: Asynchronicity was used in order to wait for the .compileComponents() to end its compiling work, which you don't use in your example. Even known Angular2 documentation states you don't need it using webpack I get an error `please call TestBed.compiledComponents` if I don't

Comment: It's been a while but I got back on testing the app. Your solution worked for me and you were right, no need for asynchronicity here. Late thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
beforeEach( async( () => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [MyComponent]
  })
  .compileComponents().then( () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance();
  });
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I think the problem is in your component template. If you use some other custom components, but didn't specify them in testing module, than Angular throws that error (of course very misleading).

So, you next options:

1. Specify all used components in TestBed configuration

   1. As variation of that you may stub all components by corresponding mocks.
2. use NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA for shallow testing as described here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#shallow-component-test

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on the answer by Zonkil I found to get this to work I had to actually set the fixture and create the component within the test.  For example:

```js
it('test the component renders',() => {      
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance; 
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(comp).toBeDefined();
    });
```